# URL rewrite for product page

Tags: magento-1.9, url-rewrite

Does anybody has a proper solution for rewriting product's URL as per following format:

http://domain/{product_id}_{title}

Any hints?

Answer (score 0):

This is not the most effective way to do but if You do not need to run it every day

```
  foreach (Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->getCollection() as $product) {
        $product->setUrlKey($product->getId() . '_'. $product->getName())->save();
    }
```

after reindex.

Comment: I have cron to url rewrite in my address, but when I add another product I must run cron. I want to set urlKey when i save product.

Comment: You can place it in catalog_product_save_after observer